# Why doesn't my dvd/cd-rom show up with the "mount" command?

Tags: mount, filesystem

So, mount is supposed to show all file systems mounted in the OS file system. However, this is not the case for my system: the drive is called cdda//:sr0/, and no part of this is revealed in the mount command.

Did the Ubuntu developers get the idea to abandon the "one file system for all devices" scheme and create a separate file system for the cd-rom drive? This is what my intuition tells me.

Thanks

Comment: When have we ever had "one file system for all devices"? Have you confused "file system" with something else? Is the disk mounted? What does `lsblk` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an audio CD. Audio CDs can't be mounted because they don't have a file system. But most desktop environments create something like a "fake mount" for audio CDs and some other devices so the users can easily access them like mountable devices (for GTK bases desktop environments like Unity and GNOME this is actually done by [GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/)).

You can identify those "fake mounts" as they are not shown as a file system path starting with `/` but as URIs starting with something like `cdda://`.

`mount` doesn't know anything about those "fake mounts".

Comment: ty, the problem is then that either the book im still reading is outdated or explaining things in a confusing manner